# Why generator in Lie Algebra is defined as the coefficient in taylor expansion of map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, infinitesimals

Booth defines the infinitesimal generator of a lie group (denote the manifold it defines by $M$) using flow $\theta_t(p)$ by calculatng the limit (mainly the derivation for $f$ in each point $p\in M$) $$X_pf=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{f(\theta_{\Delta t}(p))-f(p)}{\Delta t}.$$ However [in these lecture notes](http://www.cmth.ph.ic.ac.uk/people/d.vvedensky/groups/Chapter7.pdf) , the matrix form of the generator is defined using the taylor expansion of $\theta$ (page 8). The limit above looks a bit like a derivative but still I can't understand the equivalence between the definitions.

Why these both representations are equivalent? Can one prove it ?

Comment: Note that there's a typo in those notes. On p. 9, he says $X^2=I$, and it should, of course, be $X^2=-I$. The apparent difference in the definitions is that your displayed definition gives the action of the tangent vector on a function $f$. Geometrically, you're just taking $\dfrac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \theta_t(p)$, which is what the first term in the Taylor expansion is.

Comment: Why this definition is the action of the tangent plane on $f$? Shouldn't it be $$f(\frac{d}{dt}\theta_t(p)\mid_{t=0})$$?

Comment: No, this makes no sense. You can't feed a tangent vector into a function. But you can feed a function to a tangent vector, by taking the directional derivative of the function in the direction of the tangent vector. That's the definition you have above.

Comment: Oh, That makes sense. Thanks.